# Loading Bitmaps with Async Task in ListView Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am having trouble trying to manage bitmaps in my AsyncTask class.

I think I have everything set up fine but what happens when I try to display the images the code gets executed in a loop and the same image view ends up glitching, setting lots of different images in the same image at once(it's hard to explain). I am executing the AsyncTask from the getView method in my Adapter.

Here's my ListView adapter class, maybe someone could figure out what's wrong with it:

```
    public class SongsAdapterNew extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    ArrayList<String> names;
    ArrayList<String> images;
    Activity context;
    ImageView imageView;

    static class ViewHolder {

        private TextView text;
        private ImageView image;
    }

    public SongsAdapterNew(Activity context, ArrayList<String> names,
            ArrayList<String> images) {
        super(context, R.layout.songs_row, names);

        this.names = names;
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder mViewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.songs_row, parent, false);
            mViewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.songTextView);
            imageView = mViewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);

        }

        else {

            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        mViewHolder.text.setText(names.get(position));

        new ImageLoader().execute(mViewHolder.image, images.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Bitmap> {

        private View view;
        private Bitmap bitmap = null;
        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr;
        byte[] rawArt = null;
        Bitmap art1;
        BitmapFactory.Options bfo;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... parameters) {

            // Get the passed arguments here
            view = (View) parameters[0];
            String uri = (String) parameters[1];

            mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

            bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bfo.inSampleSize = 5;
            try {
                mmr.setDataSource(uri);
                rawArt = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawArt, 0,
                        rawArt.length, bfo);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }


            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (bitmap != null) {

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            else {

                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.songs);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not taking into account row recycling. As the user scrolls, and rows get recycled, you kick off new tasks to load new images... but the old tasks are still outstanding. Plus, with `execute()`, the old tasks will run to completion before the new ones begin. In general, this problem has been solved by many image loading libraries (e.g., Picasso, Universal Image Loader). Which ones support your particular data source, I can't say, though some should have pluggable means of stipulating the images to load.

Comment: Those image loading libraries don't support my data source, the string in which I pass AsyncTask is a direct path to that particular song on the users device, not the art.

Comment: "Those image loading libraries don't support my data source" -- yes, but you can plug in your own data sources. In the case of Universal Image Loader, craft your own scheme (e.g., `media.metadata://`), extend `BaseImageDownloader`, override `getStreamFromOtherSource()`, put your `MediaMetadataRetriever` logic in there, and register your downloader via `imageDownloader()` on `ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder`. Then, paths starting with your scheme will route to your `getStreamFromOtherSource()`, and UIL will handle all the asynchronous stuff, caching, row recycling, etc.

Comment: What CommonsWare says. Especially the first sentence. If you don't want to use a lib (but I don't see why you shouldn't) implement cancelation of an image when you recycle the view.

Comment: @Christine I would love to use a image loading library if I could, but I'm not loading images from URLS. I will try to give CommonsWare's solution a try.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you elaborate on what you mean by media.metadata:// ? is this supposed to be the location to the image? that's what I'm having troubles with. I pass the MP3 song file directory to the MediaDataRetriever, and use mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();, that returns a byte array that I have to decode to return a bitmap that contains the song art. How can I use this with Universal image loader? I'm really stuck. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have used something similar to yours, avoiding the big libraries like Picasso or Universal UIL, someday I might for faster performance. However using AsyncTask is a bit tricky but Google has document it well.

Anyway I think your problem is.

Change FROM:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

TO:

```
view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Note: You should not use the wider class scope of `imageView`. Instead you need to refer to `view` object to *access a specific image* in the row item.

This would explain your statement "setting lots of different images in the same image at once...", I think.

Comment: @Jack, Did you try this simple fix? For this stage of your development, I think this will solve your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stay away from 3rd party libraries you need to keep `Bitmap` data in your models. Since views are recycled, views (and holders) will be swapped around.

This is a rough decision, not utilizing bitmap cache, just the nuts and bolts. And it does not notify a view when `Bitmap` is ready.

Easy way is creating an Image class which holds the url and bitmap

```
public final class Image {
    public final String url;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private WeakReference<AsyncTask> imageLoaderWeakReference;

    public Image(String url) {
        this.url = url != null ? url : url;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public void load() {
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader() {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                ...
                this.bitmap = bitmap;
            }
        };
        imageLoader.execute(mViewHolder.image, url);
        imageLoaderWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(imageLoader);
    }
}
```

Then in your adapter constructor pass list of `Image` instances rather strings - `images`.

And finally in your `getView()` update the line `new ImageLoader().execute(mViewHolder.image, images.get(position));` with

```
Image image = images.get(position);
Bitmap bitmap = image.getBitmap();
if (bitmap != null) {
    // set your image view with the bitmap
}
else {
    image.load();
}
```

Eventually you can add an `ImageView` weak reference in `Image` but this requires some thinking in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As @TheOriginalAndroid said probably the source of the bug you are seeing is setting bitmap on imageView variable (which has the scope in whole adapter) instead on view (which is btw in a scope of `AsyncTask` and hold passed reference to correct `ImageView` in the list).

However in `AsyncTask` you would need [**`WeakReference`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to that image view for few reasons. First, so it doesn't hold `Bitmap` from recycling and second it would prevent crash when `ImageView` is for some reason gone but your `AsyncTask` in `onPostExecute` tries to set Bitmap on it (non existing anymore therefore **null** `ImageView`).

Check [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) post or [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sj7T_oRMbd8), guys explained it and demonstrate it pretty good there ;)